# Move snippets to VS2015 toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-snippets, toolbox

I have two development PCs, a win7 and a win10. On the win7, my vs2015 express toolbox has a tab containing the bootstrap snippets.  Although I can use the bootstrap snippets in the usual manner of right-clicking and "insert snippet",  it's very handy to see these snippets as toolbox items so I've been trying to put these snippets into a vs2015 toolbox tab on my win10 PC -  the problem is that I don't recall how the BS snippets became a toolbox tab on the win7 pc.?

It's easy to add a new tab to the toolbox and there is an option to add items to the tab. However, I've been unable to figure out how to add the BS snippets (or any set of snippets) to the toolbox. Searching the lists of items to add doesn't seem to show any snippets and browsing to the location of the snippets doesn't come up with anything that the toolbox recognizes.

I must have done some procedure on my win7 PC but I can't seem to replicate it for my win10 PC.  Or, perhaps some other extension or upgrade did this for me.

Looking for some clue as to how I can put a set of snippets in a VS2015 toolbox?

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? I'm having the same issue, I would rather not open a new question.

Comment: I have this issue as well, plus adding the suggested glyphfriend extension never goes away, even after it is installed. I don't believe the operating system should matter, I have VS community 2015 update 3 version 14.0 on server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio using Extension and Upgrades just install extensions **Bootstrap Snippet Pack** and **Glyphfriend**

Comment: I did this, and I still only have pointer and accordion in my toolbox. As well the Glyphfriend never goes away for suggested extensions to add.

Answer (score 0):

This works but bootstrap does not show in the toolbox of visual studio 2015 community edition especially when writing a django project.

Answer (score 0):

**

> 

### Alternate Answer

**

**Firstly, you could get Bootstrap Snippet Pack by clicking tool->Extensions and Updates->search Bootstrap Snippet Pack in visual studio.**

**The easiest way to add a snippet is by using the keyboard shortcut to access code snippets in Visual Studio. The magic key stroke is Crtl+K, Crtl+X.**

[You are presented with the snippet tool as shown in this img.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhIYe.png)

[Simply select Bootstrap from the menu and hit enter. You are now presented with all the code snippets for Bootstrap. Again, shown in this img.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa4d2.png)

Answer (score -1):

Goto Tools and Click Extension and Upgrades, click online on the right side of the dialog box. search for BOOTSTRAP SNIPPET PACK. Install the extension and restart VS. Hope this will work.